# ? A very long list of URL's to scrape, how do i take a break then continue?

Tags: python-3.x

Ive been wondering this for a while. I have several different very long lists of items to scrape, analyze, and save to my computer. The problem is, this is my only computer and i take it with me on the go, for example. so i dont always have an internet connection. (Or an array of other reasons that would interrupt a long scrape.) Is there any sortof protocol or library that can help me pause my program and pick up where i left off at a later date? Sorry if im being vague.

My only idea was to create a folder in my directory for every page i scrape, and have the program check if that file exists before performing the scrape and analysis, using:

```
for item in List_Items
if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(mypath + item + '/complete/')):
    scrape(item)
    analyze(item)
    save(item)

    try: os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(mypath + item + '/complete/'))
    except: pass
```

This was also beneficial, because i could open several instances of the same program to get the job done faster. But it gets a little tedious putting the same code into every program, because its got to change a little each time. Maybe if there were certain guidelines i can follow or maybe a tool i can use to help me do it? I really dont even know what to look for...thats why ive been wondering about it for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save last successful index on file? And execute program like this:

```
start = read_start_index()
scrape_list(start,...)
```

Or even write a list of successful elements and every time check if new item is in it.